# Email Servers pointing 3 MX Records

Tags: postfix

I have 3 postfix servers for my domain. How do I maintain sync between 3 emails for single domain that has 3 MX records with equal weight...

thanks,
Hari

Answer (score 3):

Either you run the mailservers as a cluster (with a shared mailstore), or you make two of the three servers as secondary/backup hosts, and have them forward mail to the primary server.